# XQuery Inject data for testing

Tags: xquery, basex

I have a library module (lib) with functions in which variables from another module (const) are used. I now want to test the functions from the lib module in a test module. I have tried changing the variables from the const module for certain tests. I am not sure if this is even possible. Here is the code:

**const** Module:

```
xquery version "3.1" encoding "utf-8";

module namespace const = "Constant";

declare variable $const:numbers:=
<numbers>
  <value s='one'>1</value>
  <value s='two'>2</value>
  <value s='three'>3</value>
  <value s='four'>4</value>
  <value s='five'>5</value>
  <value s='other'></value>
</numbers>;
```

**lib** Module:

```
xquery version "3.1" encoding "utf-8";

module namespace lib = "Library";

import module namespace con="Constant" at "const.xqm";

declare function lib:inc5($val as xs:string) as xs:integer {
  5+xs:integer($con:numbers//value[@s=$val])
};
```

**test** Module:

```
xquery version "3.1" encoding "utf-8";

module namespace test='http://basex.org/modules/xqunit-tests';

import module namespace con="Constant" at "const.xqm";
import module namespace lib="Library" at "lib.xqm";

declare %unit:test function test:inc5_add_one() {
  unit:assert-equals(lib:inc5('one'), 6)
};

declare %unit:test function test:inc5_set_other_as_10_add_ten() {
  (: replace node $con:numbers//value[@s='other'] with <value s='ten'>10</value> :)
  (: 
  $con:numbers=<numbers>
    <value s='one'>1</value>
    <value s='two'>2</value>
    <value s='three'>3</value>
    <value s='four'>4</value>
    <value s='five'>5</value>
    <value s='ten'>10</value>
  </numbers>,
  :)
  unit:assert-equals(lib:inc5('ten'), 15)
};
```

I wanted to replace the node `<value s='other'></value>` with `<value s='ten'>10</value>` in the `test:inc5_set_other_as_10_add_ten` in order to test `lib:inc5('ten')` with the expected value `15`.

What I have tried is resetting `$con:numbers` or changing the value with `replace node with` statement. But neither of these works.

My question is if it is somehow possible to change `$const:numbers` at this point so that it is used the next time `lib:inc5` is called.

Comment: `$con:numbers=<numbers>` doesn't make sense, only `let $con:numbers :=<numbers>..</numbers> return unit:assert-equals(lib:inc5('ten'), 15)` would make some sense in terms of variable bindings though I am not sure that will work for the variable from the namespace of another module.

Comment: Yes. But that doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that it’s not possible to changes the values of variables in XQuery and functional languages in general. Instead, you can pass on the result of an update expression to another operation. Your example could be rewritten as follows:

**lib** Module:

```
declare function lib:inc5($val as xs:string, $context as element()) as xs:integer {
  5 + xs:integer($context//value[@s = $val])
};
```

**test** Module:

```
declare %unit:test function test:inc5() {
  let $updated := $con:numbers update {
    replace node .//value[@s = 'other'] with <value s='ten'>10</value>
  }
  return unit:assert-equals(lib:inc5('ten', $updated), 15)
};
```

- The new `lib:inc5` function has two parameters, one for the string to be found and another one for the context element.
- The test function performs an update on the `$con:numbers` element, the result is passed on to the lib function, and the result is compared with the expected value.

Comment: "it’s not possible to changes the values of variables in XQuery and functional languages". Yes. The title of my post was misleading. I have changed it. What I am looking for is a way to modify or "inject" data for edge case tests and error handling tests. This type of data is only modified as part of the configuration during normal use of a lib, i.e. not at runtime. Adding all this configuration data as individual function parameters - just for testing purposes - is not a practical solution. (The example I show here is a simplification, not the code that is actually used).

Comment: Your use case may be too complex to give a simple answer. Feel free to write to the basex-talk mailing list.